Latex extension on liberoffice in ubuntu
I'm using Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS and have installed the LaTeX extension for LibreOffice with the tex-live full 2023.20240207-1 package. While the extension appears to be functioning and I can see its icons in LibreOffice, I'm encountering several issues. When attempting to insert a formula using this extension, the formula editor window fits my screen but I can't see the LaTeX icon below the preamble needed to generate the formula. Additionally, resizing the window is not possible. Does anyone know what might be causing this problem?
